# How to generate extremely large random numbers?

Tags: c++, random, cryptography, numbers

What is the best way to generate large random numbers (bigger than 10e32)? I have seen a lot of things for better generations (`mt19937` instead of `rand()`) but they are still relatively limited in size. I'd prefer to stick with standard libraries if possible.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;

int main() {
    long long userInput;
    cin >> userInput;
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937_64 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<long long> dist(3, userInput);
    long long randomNum = dist(gen);
    cout << randomNum;
};
//result of large inputs is maxed at around 10e20
```

Comment: `long long`, a 64 bit integer has a max value of ~10^19.  I don't know if it is mathematically a good idea, but you can generate a floating point value between 0 and 1 and then multiply that by your desired max value.

Comment: [std::uniform_real_distribution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution)?

Comment: Generate multiple random numbers and concatenate them.

Comment: How do you define "best"? Do you need bits or numbers in a large range? If you need a max value, is it possible for you to use a special number 2^x - e?

Comment: The first question you have to answer is how you want to save the number, because integer variables usually do not hold numbers bigger that 2^64.

Comment: You tagged this with "cryptography". Please note that mersenne twister, while being a really good PRNG, is not a cryptographically strong PRNG. That means you cannot reliably use it for cryptographic purposes.

Comment: First generate a random digit in the range 1..9. Then generate as many random digits in the range 0..9 as you need, concatenating each new digit with the previous digits as you go. That will give you a string of digits. Convert that string to a BigInt, bit array, byte array or whatever format you need. Remember to use a cryptographically secure RNG to pick the random digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be larger than 10<sup>32</sup> you will need 128bit generators.

There are several issues

1. Nothing in the standard is cryptographically secure RN. If you need cryptographically secure RN, you'll have to deal with either platform-specific calls, or roll something like AES or Chacha20
2. Dealing with 128bit ints is beyond standard itself, though __int128 and similar extensions are widely supported. Biggest problem is actually 128bit literals. So if you try to construct 128bits [LCG](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/linear_congruential_engine) like in standard, you won't be able to pass appropriate values for a, m, c etc
3. You might want to consider using good 64bit RN engine from standard and just glue 2 64bit random values as 128bit int, 128bit int being just a container in such case. Would work as well for cryptographically secure RN.

Just in case, below is 128bit LCG - reasonable fast, large period, very simple, works on clang and gcc

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

#define func auto

union x128
{
    uint8_t     c[16];
    __uint128_t i;
};

std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, x128 number) {
    os << "0x";
    for(auto k: number.c) {
        os << std::hex << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << uint16_t(k);
    }
    return os;
}

std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, __uint128_t number) {
    os << x128{.i=number};
    return os;
}

const __uint128_t m = x128{0xdb,0x36,0x35,0x77,0x34,0xe3,0x4a,0xbb,0x00,0x50,0xd0,0x76,0x1f,0xcd,0xfc,0x15}.i; // parameters from https://arxiv.org/pdf/2001.05304.pdf
const __uint128_t c = x128{0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x01}.i;

inline func lcg(__uint128_t xi) -> __uint128_t { // LCG
    return m*xi + c;
}

const char NL = '\n';

func main() -> int {

    std::cout << c << NL;
    std::cout << m << NL;
    
    std::cout << lcg(0x18290177731772ULL) << NL;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the interesting ways to connect a library like `GMP`. GMP provides functions for generating random integers and random floating point numbers of arbitrary size.

Example:
`mpz_random(random number.get_mpz_t(), state, 1024);`

This will generate a 1024-bit random integer.